# Passing Active Profile through command line arguments for main

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to call  Spring boot main application from my junit test case as below and setting profile as an argument as below.

```
MyApplication.main(new String[] {"-Dspring.profiles.active=local"});
```

And I have @Value configuration which reads from yml file.

yml

```
spring:
  profiles: local

subdivisions: test
```

java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class);
  }
}
```

Test case

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyApplicationTest {


  @Test
  public void testMainApplication() {

    MyApplication.main(new String[] {"-Dspring.profiles.active=local"});

  }
}
```

When I ran my test case, I am getting this error  `Could not resolve placeholder 'subdivisions' in value "${subdivisions}"`.

I am guessing the active profile is not set which is causing this error.

I tried below option to pass the active profile for Spring boot main application

```
MyApplication.main(new String[] {"spring.profiles.active=local"});
```

Thanks in advance. Any help on this is appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue, and found this syntax that worked for me :

```
    @Test
    void main() {
        MyApplication.main(new String[]{"--spring.profiles.active=dev"});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see which spring profile is set from the startup logs.
Also, if you have a test class why not just use @ActiveProfiles("local")
Also use @SpringBootTest to startup the spring boot test rather than calling main class directly